# Controlling Link Color in HTML email

Tags: html

I am database guy.  But for some inane reason the powers that be see me as the "guy who knows computers" so they think I can fix their HTML uglies.

We are sending out an HTML email newsletter.

I need to set the color of a link on the page to #6D9742

Ive tried a lot of thing like:

```
a href="http://www.mylink.com" color= 6D9742 >Click here for blah blah.
```

Could I get a little syntax help?

Comment: try `<a href="http://www.mylink.com" style="color: #6D9742" >Click here for blah blah</a>`. BTW its easy to google.

Comment: this should help you http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<a href="http://www.mylink.com" style="color: #6D9742" >Click here for blah blah.</a>
```

another time use [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css). It's realy good website.

for this question read : [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve it.

1. Using `style` attribute: The style attribute specifies an inline style for an element.

HTML Code

```
<a href="http://www.mylink.com" style="color: #6D9742" > click here </a>
```

1. Using styling in your css file.

HTML Code

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://www.mylink.com" > click here </a>
```

Css Code

```
#mylink{
color: #6D9742
}
```